# MobileFirst 8 Migration : How to generate same device UUID in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

We try to migrate from Worklight 6.2.0.01.20161110-0936 to MobileFirst 8 APP.

But we got a problem that we must use **same devie UUID** after migration.

According to [official note](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/product-overview/release-notes/deprecated-discontinued/):

[image]

We know that WL.Device.getID and device.uuid are not equal in Android.

We can use same code to generate same device UUID in Android MobileFirst 8 APP.

But we don't know how to generate same device UUID in iOS

Question : How to get same ios device UUID after migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to get is to use "getWLUniqueDeviceId" API of "WLDeviceAuthManager.h".

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution myself :

The Worklight 6.2 version stores the device UUID in keychain

You need to turn on keychain Sharing in Xcode Capabilities

And add worklight.group to the Keychain Groups

[image]

Then you can use "WLUUID" as the KeyChain item identifier

For example :

```
NSString *keychainItemIdentifier = @"WLUUID";
KeychainItemWrapper *keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] 
           initWithIdentifier:keychainItemIdentifier accessGroup:nil];
id item =[keychain objectForKey:@"v_Data"];
NSLog(@"Device UUID : %@",item);
```

You can get the following results:

[image]